# Is it possible to create an application whitelist for user privileges in Windows?

Tags: windows, privileges, whitelist, local-security-policy

Is it possible to grant a user a specific privilege, but then restrict the use of that privilege to a specific list of applications?  For example, lets say that I have a special debugging application that I want use on a normal account that requires the `SeDebugPrivilege` to be enabled to work.  However, I want every application other than the aforementioned debugger running under the normal account to be restricted from using this privilege.  Is this possible?  If so, how can this be done programmatically?

Comment: No, that isn't possible.  The security model doesn't allow it.  (However, you shouldn't need SeDebugPrivilege to use a debugger.)

Comment: Re-reading the question, what you *can* do is to split the application into two parts.  One part is the user interface, which runs in the user's security context; the other is a service, which runs in a privileged security context.  But the service must be responsible for determining which actions the user is permitted to take, because the user interface part can still be replaced or subverted by the user.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That's actually related to another question I wanted to ask: Is it possible for an application to use the permissions of an account different from the one it's running under?

Comment: This is called [impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376391(v=vs.85).aspx).  System services can use impersonation, and so can regular applications that are running with administrator privilege, but non-elevated applications can't.  Note that you can only impersonate after you've obtained a token for the account in question, which requires the username and password, unless you can copy the token from an existing process or session.

Comment: What about elevating a thread under a LUA account?

Comment: The UAC mechanism only allows you to elevate a new process, not a single thread.

Comment: Would it be possible for a thread to obtain an elevated LUA token?

Comment: Sort of, but not really.  You can use UAC to launch a new elevated process, and have that process give the original process an elevated token.  But the original process, lacking impersonation rights, won't be able to *use* the token.  There might be some way around that, but I can't think of one offhand.

Comment: Would enabling the impersonation privilege on the LUA end of the account be too much of a security risk?  It says [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/01/11/what-s-in-a-token-part-2-impersonation.aspx) that a malicious program could use the `LsaLogonUser` function along with the impersonation privilege to do whatever it wanted on a system.  Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to give the restricted token debug privilege - that's one of privileges stripped out by UAC.  Assuming it is possible, it is moderately risky, e.g., [see this paper](http://www.blakewatts.com/namedpipepaper.html).  The LsaLogonUser function requires SeTcbPrivilege, so you would have to be running as local system to use it, and I don't believe it is straightforward to synthesize a token even then - but yes, it is at least theoretically possible, given admin access.

Comment: Theoretically possible?

Comment: It is my understanding that it is possible, but I don't know of anyone having successfully done it.

Comment: You mentioned only the debug privilege in your last comment.  What about the impersonation privilege?

Comment: Typo, sorry.  I meant impersonation privilege.

Comment: What about icacls.exe?

Comment: What about it?  It supersedes cacls.exe, for manipulating file permissions from the command line.